# assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

Tags: c, windows, winapi

When i try to compile the following code:

```
#define BUFSIZE MAX_PATH 


//....


TCHAR sz_VolumeName[BUFSIZE] ;//11
HANDLE hSearch ;//12
hSearch  = FindFirstVolume(sz_VolumeName , BUFSIZE) ;//13
```

It gives me the ERROR:

```
[Warning] assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast
```

- with the problem in line 13

What going wrong here ?

EDIT : for example :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>


#define BUFSIZE MAX_PATH


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
  {

   TCHAR sz_VolumeName[BUFSIZE] ;
   HANDLE hSearch ;
   hSearch  = FindFirstVolume(sz_VolumeName , BUFSIZE) ; 
   printf("First Volume Name  : %s \n" , sz_VolumeName) ; 
   FindVolumeClose(hSearch) ;
   getchar() ;
   system("PAUSE"); 
   return 0;
       }
```

Comment: Have you included `windows.h`? (or `WinBase.h` if you're on Windows 7 or Vista)

Comment: That error suggests to me that `FindFirstVolume()` is actually declared to return an integer instead of a `HANDLE` as documented. If I look in winbase.h, it is declared to return a HANDLE, but it is also documented that it exists in FileApi.h instead in modern OS versions, and I don't have FileApi.h available to look at, but maybe your app is using the FileApi.h version and it is being declared differently in that file?

Comment: @RemyLebeau , I have only the usual declaration in winbase.h

Comment: @user22323 Can you then post a minimal example that others can attempt to compile?

Comment: @user22323: since you are using `TCHAR`, you should use `_tprintf()` instead of `printf()`: `_tprintf(_T("First Volume Name  : %s \n"), sz_VolumeName);`.  `_tprintf()` is declared in `tchar.h`.

Comment: the problem is with the function FindFirstVolume , the rest can be ignored .

Comment: @user22323: what's it exactly? What did you find?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Function `FindFirstVolume` is undeclared, which makes the compiler to assume it returns `int`, when in reality it is supposed to return `HANDLE`. The warning you are getting refers specifically to your attempt to implicitly convert the `int` return value to `HANDLE` type (`HANDLE` is actually a pointer type).

Most likely the declaration of `FindFirstVolume` in Windows API headers is hidden by some conditional compilation directive. You probably have to `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500` to "enable" that function's declaration.

Add

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

before including Windows API headers and see if it helps. If this is indeed the culprit, set `_WIN32_WINNT` to `0x0500` globally in your project settings. This is actually something you should always do unconditionally for all modern Windows projects that use MS header files.

Comment: If it were undeclared, then the compiler should be failing with an error saying as much, instead of producing different code with different behavior.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: No. Remember that this is a C language question, not C++. In the C world only C99 compilers are required to fail for undeclared functions. A "classic" C89/90 compiler does not fail for undeclared functions. Instead it makes up the missing declaration with `int` return type. This is exactly what is happening in this case. I presume the OP is using a C89/90 compiler.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: And even a C99 compiler is perfectly allowed to compile code that calls undeclared functions, as long as it issues a diagnostic message, like the warning from the original post. There no such requirement as "failing with an error" in C/C++ compiler world.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
hSearch  = FindFirstVolume((LPWSTR)sz_VolumeName , BUFSIZE);
```

Comment: If the app were set to compile for Ansi and not Unicode, ie `TCHAR` maps to `char` instead of `wchar_t`, then this code would fail to compile at all.  Never do `LPSTR`/`LPWSTR` type-casts like this anyway, it is just plain wrong.

Answer (score -1):

HANDLE is a rather strange data type.  It is similar to a pointer. The reason that you get that error is the FindFirstVolume() function seems to return an integer.  This is why your error mentions an integer.  You are assigning the (kind of) pointer hsearch to an integer, which tells it to point at a different point in memory, instead of actually assigning that integer value to it. If you want hsearch to point to the integer coming out of FindFirstVolume, then you need to do this:

```
*hSearch  = FindFirstVolume(sz_VolumeName , BUFSIZE) ;//13
```

If you then wanted to access that integer, you would do this:

```
int myInt = *hSearch
```

Because I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish in your code, I hope this helps.

Comment: Could you be helpful and explain what is wrong? Maybe suggest an edit?  That's how this is supposed to work, not just you throwing stones at people. You seem to have submitted an answer in the comments section above by mistake.

Comment: "`HANDLE` is similar to a pointer" is not true. It is not **similar to** a pointer, it **is** a pointer. And as such, dereferencing a `HANDLE`, especially an uninitialized `HANDLE`, to stuff an integer value into it is wrong and will corrupt memory. `FindFirstVolume()` returns a `HANDLE`, not an integer. In the off-chance that `FindFirstVolume()` were declared wrong and happened to return an integer, it would still represent a `HANDLE` since that is what the API actually returns, so the correct thing to do is type-cast the integer into a `HANDLE` instead.

Comment: Why don't you submit that into an answer?

Comment: No, type-casting the integer into a `HANDLE` isn't correct either. The correct thing is to figure out why there's no declaration of `FindFirstVolume()` in scope, and correct that.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson: yes, correcting the definition of `FindFirstVolume()` is the correct thing to do. However, if it were defined and in scope, the type-cast would be the next solution (as long as the code is being compiled for 32-bit, that is) if the definition was wrong.

Comment: If it's defined and in scope, you wouldn't be getting the 'pointer from integer without a cast' warning. (And if the definition is _wrong_... are you **trying** to make demons fly out of your nose?)